# Problems when I'm driving lack of power

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, power, intermittent-problems, monte-carlo

1973 Chevy Monte Carlo 350 4bbl small block having problems with the car want to put in drive and take all driving it doesn't seem to want to go cast 40 miles an hour so I figured trying to change the transmission filter once I did I got a new vacuum modulator, new hose's,transmission fluid. So I don't know what the problem is can somebody please help me

Comment: Welcome to the site. What exactly is your question? What have you done to diagnose the issue? What have you done to fix *anything* (tuneup, etc)? As it stands, this semi-quasi-question is way too broad to be answered coherently.

Comment: I can't remember,  a Monte doesn't have a catylst converter, right?

Comment: @Macc Burnah .If you have a vacuum leak it will run like a dog .Check all the hoses around the carb and check the carb gasket .